# Conditional xpath using precompiled xpath

Tags: java, parsing, xpath

I am using XPATH in my project and i need to traverse through the nodes conditionally

```
public static String getNodeContentForMultipleTag1(XPathExpression expr,Document doc) {
    try {

        NodeList typeResult = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < typeResult.getLength(); i++) {
            Node typeResultNode = typeResult.item(i);
            System.out.println(typeResultNode.getTextContent());
        }
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed parsing expression",e);
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {
    String s="<ex><DtTm><TxDtTm><Cd>ABCD</Cd><dt>1234</dt></TxDtTm><TxDtTm><Cd>XYZ</Cd><dt>891</dt></TxDtTm></DtTm></ex>";
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    DocumentBuilder db= XpathInstanceUtil.getDocumentBuilderFactory().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(inputStream);
    XPath xpath = XpathInstanceUtil.getXPathFactory().newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/ex/DtTm/TxDtTm");
    inputStream.close();
    long st = System.currentTimeMillis();
    getNodeContentForMultipleTag1(expr, doc);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end-st);

    long st1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    getNodeContentForMultipleTag1(expr, doc);
    long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end1-st1);

}
```

if the Cd value is ABCD i should get 1234 as result.
I have tried the following

```
public static String getNodeContentForMultipleTag(String expresssion,String expectedNode,String expectedExpressionTag,Document doc) {
    try {
        XPath xpath = XpathInstanceUtil.getXPathFactory().newXPath();
        NodeList typeResult = (NodeList) evaluateXPath(doc,expresssion,xpath,XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList valueResult= (NodeList) evaluateXPath(doc,expectedExpressionTag,xpath,XPathConstants.NODESET);
        //NodeList typeResult = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expresssion,doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        //NodeList valueResult = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expectedExpressionTag,doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < typeResult.getLength(); i++) {
            Node typeResultNode = typeResult.item(i);
            typeResultNode.getParentNode().removeChild(typeResultNode);
            Node valueResultNode = valueResult.item(i);
            if(typeResultNode.getTextContent().equals(expectedNode) && valueResultNode!=null){
                valueResultNode.getParentNode().removeChild(valueResultNode);
                return  valueResultNode.getTextContent();
            }
        }
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed parsing expression"+expresssion,e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is how expressions look like

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        String s="<ex><DtTm><TxDtTm><Cd>ABCD</Cd><dt>1234</dt></TxDtTm><TxDtTm><Cd>XYZ</Cd><dt>891</dt></TxDtTm></DtTm></ex>";
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        DocumentBuilder db= XpathInstanceUtil.getDocumentBuilderFactory().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(inputStream);
        String ss = getNodeContentForMultipleTag("/ex/DtTm/TxDtTm/Cd", "XYZ", "/ex/DtTm/TxDtTm/dt", doc);
        System.out.println(ss);
    }
```

But the its performance is very low.How it should be changed to parse efficiently

Comment: Performance depends on the product you are using but the code you have shown us will run with any product that implements the Java XPath API. Performance also depends on which version of Java you are using. You should also quantify what performance you require and what you are actually getting, so that we can assess how drastic the needed changes are.

Comment: Yeah i tried java xpath.Actually my xml looks bigger than what is posted.There is huge performance impact because of xpath.I dont reuse the expressions.So i have to evaluate more than 1000 time for one XML which is generating huge volume of Xobject

Comment: With xpath i am able to parse 200000 in 7 min with huge memory consumption

Comment: You haven't actually shown the XPath expressions you are passing as arguments to getNodeContentForMultipleTag(). And I don't understand what the first function getNodeContentForMultipleTag1 has to do with the question. And why aren't you reusing the expressions if you know that will make a difference?

Comment: I have edited my question.getNodeContentForMultipleTag1() is the way the tried to compile the expression.But that didn't work.I am using com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems completely bizarre. Why are you doing all this work in Java rather than in XPath? Why are you modifying the DOM tree as you search it?

You just need to execute the XPath expression `/ex/DtTm/TxDtTm[Cd='ABCD']/dt` and you're there.

Comment: Thanks for reply.How can i make Cd value parameterised?

Comment: Put a variable in the XPath expression `[Cd=$p1]` and then bind a value for `$p1` using `xpath.setXPathVariableResolver(....)`